# ¿Cómo eliminar un domain-class en grails 3.3.8?

Tags: grails

Tengo un proyecto en grails en el cual tengo un domain-class de nombre `Participante.groovy`. La cuestión es que ya no lo requiero y por lo tanto lo quiero eliminar, sin embargo cuando lo elimino y uso el comando `run-app`, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined
> in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'methodValidationPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot
> resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting
> constructor argument; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via
> constructor failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor
> threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type
> proyecto.colaborativo.Participante not present
```

Realmente ya no lo estoy usando en ningún otro archivo(controlador, vista, o servicio), entonces no entiendo por qué me grails necesita que exista ese archivo.
Por ahora lo he vuelto a crear porque si no no puedo correr el proyecto, pero el único código que tiene es el siguiente:

```
class Participante {

}
```

Comment: ¿Hiciste un clean o un rebuild?

Comment: Ha funcionado haciendo clean.

Comment: Lo imaginé, que bueno que funcionó.